# Looking for effecient way to store nested data with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, nested-sets, adjacency-list, materialized-path-pattern

I've been trying to find an efficient way to represent nested data in java/hibernate.  My initial solution was a parent/child list with a self referencing join, but there are obvious pitfalls to this technique when building reports in SQL.  I was looking into nested set and materialized path, but I was hoping there would be a way to represent nested data native to hibernate that is also efficient to query via SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could have your nested data in the form of an inheritance hierarchy then you can have a look into the [Inheritance Mapping Strategies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html) of Hibernate. I've used them and if configured well then they are quite good.